# Error en la consola: .push() y .unshift() no son una función

Tags: javascript, array, funciones, bucle-for

me encuentro haciendo un trabajo practico que me pide que haga una función que tome como parámetro un array y si este tiene ceros que los pase todos al final del array, hasta ahí todo joya, el tema es cuando lo quiero probar en la consola me sale que .push() y .unshift() no son funciones. Acá esta lo que hice:

```js
function moveZeros(array) {
  let array2 = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === 0) {
      array2 = array2.push(array[i]);
    } else {
      array2 = array2.unshift(array[i]);
    };
  };
  console.log(array2);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Tanto la función `push()` como la función `unshift()` tienen como parámetro de salida la nueva longitud del **array** por lo que en la siguiente vuelta del bucle `array2` no contiene un array, si no un entero, del que no puedes invocar ninguna de las dos funciones. Y de ahí se te notifica ese error.

No te hace falta capturar el resultado de ninguna de las dos funciones ya que afectan directamente al **array** desde el que se usan.

```js
function moveZeros(array) {
  let array2 = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === 0) {
      array2.push(array[i]);
    } else {
      array2.unshift(array[i]);
    };
  };

  console.log(array2);
};

moveZeros([1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 2]);
```

**Referencias:** [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/push), [unshift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/unshift)

Answer (score 1):

## Filter

### Esta seria otra opción

```
    function moveZeros(arr){
      let arr0 = arr.filter (e => e !== 0)
      let arr1 = arr.filter (cero => cero === 0);
      return [...arr0, ...arr1];
    }  
    moveZeros([false,1,0,1,2,0,1,3,"a"])
```

Te dejo la documentación oficial:

[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

Una solución alternativa a tu trabajo es usar [sort()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp)

```js
console.log(
    [0, 3, 2, 0, 5, 1, 0]
        .sort((_, b) => b == 0 ? -1 : 0)
);

//Esta seria una forma mas precisa, conserva el orden de los 0
console.log(
    [0, 3, 2, 0, 5, 1, 0]
        .sort((a, b) => b == 0 ? b - Math.abs(a) : 0)
);
```

Puedes verificar con un json que el orden de como aparecen los 0 se conserva

```js
console.log(
    [
        { numero: 0, indice: 0 },
        { numero: 3, indice: 1 },
        { numero: 2, indice: 2 },
        { numero: 0, indice: 4 },
        { numero: 5, indice: 5 },
        { numero: 1, indice: 6 },
        { numero: 0, indice: 6 }
    ]
        .sort((a, b) => b.numero == 0 ? b.numero - Math.abs(a.numero) : 0)
);

console.log(
    [
        { numero: 0, indice: 0 },
        { numero: 3, indice: 1 },
        { numero: 2, indice: 2 },
        { numero: 0, indice: 4 },
        { numero: 5, indice: 5 },
        { numero: 1, indice: 6 },
        { numero: 0, indice: 6 }
    ]
        .sort((_, b) => b.numero == 0 ? -1 : 0)
);
```